# Non-specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Most tags are standard categories and either subfields of Economics or specific concepts.

Less specific tags are not useful if, once invented, people misuse them. One example is [soft-question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question). I don't know what the purpose of its invention was (sounds quite meta to me), but I can't find a common theme to the questions tagged with it.

Ignoring for a moment that it seems to be a tag which is rather meta, can we agree to *always* write at least a short summary for a new tag when we create it? Tag creation requires a specific reputation threshold, so it's up to the established users to enforce up this standard.