# Delete Unnecesary Tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

As well as [merging a few tags](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/should-we-start-dealing-with-duplicate-tags?cb=1)

It would probably be a good idea to delete a few unnecessary tags as well.

**Post any tags you feel can be deleted.**

For example, I think that the tags  `nobel-prize` and `noises` don't really add anything. If you want to know econ.stackexchange has on those, the search function still works.

I'd say once a tag has been suggested here and there is no dissent, people can just remove the tags from posts that use them.

This is also relevant:

[Non-specific tags](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/non-specific-tags)

Comment: Could you post `nobel-prize` and `noises` as answers so we can vote on them?

Comment: @Ubiquitous done... how do we delete these tags?

Comment: See the answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71129/274708. In short, it seems tags with no questions are automatically deleted every 24 hours. So all we need to do is to remove the offending tag from every question and wait.

Comment: @Ubiquitous I just noticed nobel-prize was a tag created by you! Hope you're not too offended at my suggestion to delete it. haha

Comment: No, not at all. The way we find which tags are appropriate on the site is to create them and see which ones stick. Some are bound to fall by the wayside!

Comment: @Ubiquitous can we/you "delete" the top answers that have been unlinked, in order to keep it clean and get some attention to the lower rated/new posts?

Comment: Yes, done. I will do the same in the duplicate tags question.

Answer (score 4):

`pacman-conjecture` and `coase-conjecture` are both tagged to a single question. They sound to me too narrow to be a tag - but I might be mistaken. I rather suggest something like `industrial-organization` for that question.

Answer (score 1):

`firm` could probably be deleted. It has been used four times but I'd think that it is too broad.